# Q: how do you parse out a word that might have a word space word combo?

Tags: parsing, logging, datadog, grok, fail2ban

Almost have these logs nailed down but having a hard time with a section of the log that provides the fail2ban action. It is usually a single word, but sometimes it is two words with a space between them. I am not sure how to address this issue and greatly appreciate any assistance. I have done a fair amount of research but not found a definitive answer, even trying various solutions.

In these examples below, you will see **Restore Ban**, **Ban**, and **Found**. This is what I am trying to isolate.

**Sample logs:**

```
2021-10-20 19:50:39,638 fail2ban.actions        [31705]: NOTICE  [sshd] Restore Ban 68.183.15.177
2021-10-20 16:08:16,315 fail2ban.actions        [6428]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 141.98.10.121
2021-10-20 17:21:23,807 fail2ban.filter         [6428]: INFO    [sshd] Found 159.75.130.111 - 2021-10-20 17:21:23
```

**Current grok:**

```
fail2banRule01 %{date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"):Datetime}\s+fail2ban.%{word}\s+\[%{number:PID}\]\:\s+%{word:Level}\s+\[%{word:Jail}\]\s+%{word:ActionType}\s+%{ipv4:ClientIP}(\s+-\s+%{date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):ActionDate})?
```

NOTE: This will be within Datadog's log processing structure.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the issue. Change from word type to data.

**Here is the grok now:**

fail2banRule01 %{date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"):Datetime}\s+fail2ban.%{word}\s+[%{number:PID}]:\s+%{word:Level}\s+[%{word:Jail}]\s+%{data:ActionType}\s+%{ipv4:ClientIP}(\s+-\s+%{date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):ActionDate})?

**Log that was an issue:**

```
2021-10-20 19:50:39,638 fail2ban.actions        [31705]: NOTICE  [sshd] Restore Ban 68.183.15.177
```

**Output using data:**

```
{
  "Datetime": 1634759439638,
  "PID": 31705,
  "Level": "NOTICE",
  "Jail": "sshd",
  "ActionType": "Restore Ban",
  "ClientIP": "68.183.15.177"
}
```